# Why does my app listen on port 80 instead of port 3000 as I set it running inside docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

**What I'm trying?**

I'm trying to run my nodejs app inside a docker container and want to use it outside of the container(through my browser on port 3000).

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**app.ts(Relevant portion)**

```
const port = process.env.port || 3000;   
let app = express();
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

**command I'm using to run**

`$ docker run --net=host <imgName>`

**OS** --> Windows 7

And in the Oracle Virtual Box I've changed network settings to bridged networks.

The command runs successfully and the server starts listening on port 80. And I can access it from outside the container on port 80 through postman,curl,browser,etc.

Where I am doing wrong? How can I make it to listen on port 3000? And also how is it even able to listen on port if I haven't `exposed` it explicitly?

I think the docker is passing `port` as an `environment variable` and setting it to 80 as I am not passing any environment variable myself.

Please help I'm very new to `docker`.

Comment: You're using host mode networking in which the concept of exposing ports are meaningless because the network is shared with the host and not namespaced

Comment: @Sathya So how can I do this on port 3000? Could you please explain? I've just started learning docker.

Comment: docker run -p 3000:3000 <imgName>

Comment: @opHASnoNAME that will not work because like I said, with host mode networking the published ports are ignored

Comment: post the contents of `docker ps` and `docker logs <container id>`

Comment: @Sathya Thanks for all your help! It was listening to the port `80` instead of `3000` because the compilation from typescript is somehow not happening properly by `npm run build`. When I compile it on my host machine and the `docker build .`. It works with command `docker -p 3000:3000 <imageName>`. I also had to add a rule in port forwarding section of NAT in vm virtual box.

Answer (score 4):

Just exposing in your `Dockerfile` won't do it for you. You will need to map it when you do `docker run` or execute using `docker-example.yaml`.

To achieve that you will need to use `$ docker run -p 3000:3000`. Following that you won't need to use `--net=host` that should be the reason why the service is available on port 80.

Hope it helps!

Cheers!