# Nodejs port change in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

There is a Node js application in the docker container, it works on port `3149`, but I need the container to run on port `3000`, how can I change the port and register it in the Dockerfile without changing anything in the application code?

**dokerfile**

````
COPY package*.json /

ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org > /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
    apt update -qqy && \
    apt -qqy install \
    ruby \
    ruby-dev \
    yarn \
    locales \
    autoconf automake gdb git libffi-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev \
    build-essential

RUN gem install compass

RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en

COPY . .

RUN npm ci && \
    node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js client && \
    rm -rf /app/id_rsa \
    rm -rf /root/.ssh/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ] ```
````

Comment: Here the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015565/why-does-my-app-listen-on-port-80-instead-of-port-3000-as-i-set-it-running-insid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the container running on port 3000 you have specify this once you run the container using `--port` or `-p` options/flags, and note that [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) does not publish the port :

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

so you have to run the container with `-p` option from the terminal:

```
docker run -p 3000:3149 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

when you run the container map port 3000 on the host to port 3149 in the container e.g.

```
docker run -p 3000:3149 image
```